# Homothetic Production Technologies

Tags: reference-request, production-function, producer-theory, cost

Can someone suggest a good resource on homothetic technologies and what properties they imply about cost function, profit function, input demands, output supply etc? Also is it possible to have inferior inputs with homothetic technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic reference on this topic (as suggested by my professor) is the book;

Theory of Cost and Production Functions by Ronald Shepherd.